# How to save the registry after removing asset from it?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How to save the registry after removing asset from it?

**After removing the asset from registry,  Do I need to save it with any api method ?** 
**Use Case :**
1. Remove the asset from the asset listing registry.
2. Save the asset listing asset registry.

Comment: No, you don't need to save the registry after performing any calls such as add/update/remove

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need to update the asset by calling the Runtime API
First, you need to remove the asset from the registry and then you need to update back with the new structure.

For an easy way, you can use the DELETE request to remove your asset data via REST API calls.